# Index outside of the bounds of the array in a list

Tags: c#

I have the following code :

```
 public List<IAction> Dispatch(string[] arg)
   {
       int time=0;
       int i = 0;
       int j = 0;
       List<IAction> t = new List<IAction>(10);
       do
       {
           if (arg[j][0] == '/') // I get index out of bounds here
           {
               Options opt = new Options();                   

               time = opt.Option(arg[j]);
               j++;
           }
           else
           {
               if (int.Parse(arg[j]) >= 0 && int.Parse(arg[j]) <= 20)
               {
                   t.Add(new ComputeParam(int.Parse(arg[j])));
                   i++;
                   j++;                      
               }
           }

       } while (i != arg.Length);
       for (int z = 0; z < t.Count; z++)
       {
           ((ComputeParam)t[z]).Time = time;
       }
       return t;
   }
```

Why does the error happen... I just pass the arguments and if they are numbers I add them to a list, if not I set an option and move on. What is the problem here?

Edit : I pass 2 /t:Med 2 3 
those are the arguments. I aleready checked it arg[1] (in this case) is null, but it's not.

Comment: `arg` is empty or the string in `arg[j]` has no characters. You cannot index what isn't there.

Comment: what if no argument is passed?

Comment: Did you put a break point here? arg[j][0]. What is the value of args at this point

Comment: Make sure that arg is not null

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: That looks like an answer to me, not a comment. ;-)

Comment: I print arg[j] and yes, "/t:Med" appears as it should. so it's not null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple of possible issues here:

1. If `arg[]` is empty, you will get the exception
2. If `arg[j]` is an empty string, you will get the exception
3. If you have any options, you will get the exception on a later execution of the loop, because `j` is being incremented, but `i` is not.

I think this will fix it:

```
public List<IAction> Dispatch(string[] arg)
{
   int time=0;
   List<IAction> t = new List<IAction>(10);
   for (int j = 0; j < arg.Length; j++)
   {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg[j]) && arg[j][0] == '/')
       {
           Options opt = new Options();                   

           time = opt.Option(arg[j]);
       }
       else
       {
           if (int.Parse(arg[j]) >= 0 && int.Parse(arg[j]) <= 20)
           {
               t.Add(new ComputeParam(int.Parse(arg[j])));
               // Don't need to increment i                
           }
       }

   }
   for (int z = 0; z < t.Count; z++)
   {
       ((ComputeParam)t[z]).Time = time;
   }
   return t;
}
```

Comment: Now I just feel silly. I used i instead of j. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You get this when you try to index an element where there is no element, as in, usually you are indexing elements when the array is smaller than you expect.

In your case, either:

- The value of `j` is greater than or equal to `arg.Length` so `arg[j]` throws out of bounds.
- The string in `arg[j]` has no characters so `arg[j][0]` throws out of bounds.

You can test the length using the `Length` property of arrays. `string` also has a `Length` property.

Just as an aside, you don't increment `j` in all cases and you don't even seem to use `i` other than in the check, but `j` could have been incremented further than `i` meaning your `while (i != args.Length)` won't defend you against `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also, the check should *at least* be `while (i < args.Length)`